# how to filter a list of query result set in django

Tags: django

hi i have below code working fine:

```
if getattr(hotel_main, "X", 1):
        hotels1 = hotels.filter(Q(X=True))
        for hotel in hotels1:
            if models.CalendarDay.objects.filter(hotel=hotel, date=date).count() == 0:
                similar_venues.append(hotel)
```

I reused above code again and again to check different conditions like Q(Y=True),Q(Y=True),Q(Z=True)

if i can filter a list based on the condition i can get rid of repeating code... i want something like this: **similar_venues.filter(Q(X=True))**  Any help please...

Comment: what is simllar venues here? is it a queryset or a list

Comment: Check out Django Predicate. Might be useful. https://github.com/ptone/django-predicate

Comment: If I do not misunderstand it, you are looking for something like `hotels1 = hotels.filter(Q(X=True)|Q(Y=True)|Q(Z=True)|)` which means any of (X,Y,Z) values can be `True`

Comment: I am trying to check the date availability of a particular hotel and if yes the i am trying to filter them based on the conditions. So i thought to check the date first and save it into a list and then filter the list later on... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you asked:

```
filter_on_x = [obj for obj in similar_venues if obj.X]
filter_on_y = [obj for obj in similar_venues if obj.Y]
```

and so on for all the X, Y, Z

Answer (score 0):

You can write conditions in a list:

```
conditions = [ Q(Y=True),Q(Y=True),Q(Z=True) ]
if getattr(hotel_main, "X", 1):
    q_date = Q( calendarday__date = date )
    for q in conditions:
        for hotel in hotels.filter( q_date & q).distinct():
            similar_venues.append(hotel)
```

Comment: @user1529342, now I understand your question.